# pbkdf2 objective c compare hashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

i found an implementation of pbkdf2 hashing algorithm , I can calculate the hash, but i don't know how i can compare the hash with a password if i do a log in.
can somebody give me a hint?
here is my implementation of the hasing algorithm

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>

...

// Makes a random 256-bit salt
- (NSData*)generateSalt256 {
    unsigned char salt[32];
for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
    salt[i] = (unsigned char)arc4random();
}
return [NSData dataWithBytes:salt length:32];
}

...

// Make keys!
NSString* myPass = @"MyPassword1234";
NSData* myPassData = [myPass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* salt = [self generateSalt256];

// How many rounds to use so that it takes 0.1s ?
int rounds = CCCalibratePBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, myPassData.length, salt.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256, 32, 100);

// Open CommonKeyDerivation.h for help
unsigned char key[32];
CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, myPassData.bytes, myPassData.length, salt.bytes, salt.length,     kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256, rounds, key, 32);
```

Answer (score 1):

PBKDF2 is usually used to generate an encryption key from your password; it's not used to hash like you would use MD5. How are you using it for login? Something like [LastPass](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/security-options/password-iterations-pbkdf2/)?

Normally one sends the password (after salt and hash) to the server, and the server does the comparison, not the client. Do you have a different use case?

Comment: I was thinking to use it for password hashing because somebody suggested these algorithms in a comment on my previous post "SHA1 is too fast for passwords. Use bcrypt or PBKDFv2"( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577582/sha1-encoding-c-sharp-and-objective-c ). However it was not clear how i could use it for login then. The use case is if somebody registers, the password is hashed and salted and the hash is stored in the database. Second use case: if a user logs in the password is hashed and compared to the hash in the database. Which algorithm would you suggest? must available in c# & iOS.

Comment: bcrypt and PBKDF2 are good for slowly creating a secret key from a password. "Slowly" so that bad guys can't brute-force guess all possibilities. Keys are for encryption, not login. What form is your server expecting you to send your password? In the clear? Hashed and salted?

Comment: it is expecting hashed and salted.

Comment: Do you have a spec for what exactly the server expects? It probably will send you a salt to use. Did they specify that the server expects PBKDF2?